# Suspend the process and not to cancel it after SSH logout

Tags: unix, ssh, freebsd, putty

I'm loging via putty (SSH) to server on which execute my webserver program. With CTRL+Z and bg commands is webserver running on background but if I logout, the process is terminated. How can I prevent the termination after logout? Operation system on server is FreeBSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `nohup` when starting, or you can use `disown` (in Bash or ZSH) interactively:

```
% run_long_script
# Ctrl-Z
% bg
% disown
```